# Why can I set a character array larger than I'm reserving with malloc()?

Tags: c, string, memory, dynamic

Why does this print out "test"?:

```
    char *str;
    str = (char *)malloc(1);
    str[0] = 't';
    str[1] = 'e';
    str[2] = 's';
    str[3] = 't';
```

I'm trying to dynamically expand a string and trying to understand how malloc/realloc works and the above behavior is confusing me as to malloc()/realloc() is advisable for expanding char* .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: because it is C and not java... bound checking are let to very low level paging based on big blocks. If it looks like to work, you might be sure you corrupted other parts of your program, it will fail unexpectidly somewhere else... C require from programmers to take care of not doing that...

Comment: Minor point in the broader context of the question (which has already been answered), but don't cast malloc in standard C either.  Unlike C++, it's considered bad practice to do it in C, and all it can really do is hide an error (not including stdlib.h) and make code maintenance issues, ex: you change the type of the variable used in the malloc call 6 months later, then have to fix up the casts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are writing beyond the end of your "officially" allocated memory.  Most memory allocation systems have a minimum size that they use internally and you are probably not actually going beyond *that* boundary, so your code appears to be working.  If you make the string long enough, you will eventually pass a boundary that matters to the OS and your program will crash.

You could assign a random number to `str` and then treat it as a pointer, too, and every so often it will actually work.  But you have no idea what you might be writing over.  Same with your memory overrun.  The memory allocator may pack allocations tightly enough that you are overwriting something else in your program.

You should **ALWAYS** ensure that you do not go beyond the bounds of any array.  **EVER**.  Buffer overruns (and underruns) are exactly what many, many hacks take advantage of to break into systems.  Make sure you don't allow them and you're already better that quite a bit of old code out there.

Answer (score 4):

Undefined Behavior means anything could happen.  Including appearing to "work", nothing at all, OR a segmentation fault.  Your sample code is indeed bad, but the C Standard doesn't guarantee that it will do anything "useful", nor that anything "bad" will necessarily happen at compile time or at run time.

Answer (score 1):

This code is plain wrong, obviously - you're accessing memory past the array boundaries.

It works, because:

- there's no mechanism in place to detect each and every invalid memory access. Many such attempts would cause a segmentation fault, but it doesn't happen every time. Many times such a buggy code simply overwrites some random variable, etc. - this is one of the reasons why debugging issues like this can quickly become a nightmare. I suggest you get yourself familiar with [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).
- in this particular case I'd say that `malloc()` rounds up the allocated chunk of memory to (at least) multiple of 4, so in this case it might work as expected. But still it's a bug.
- you also don't terminate the string explicitly, and again - the behavior is really random, `str[4]` can have any value, really. It depends on many things - from heap allocator implementation to pure coincidence.